# Complete list of versification differences in the Tanakh

Tags: bible, old-testament, resource-request, versification

As already said in [a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11969/are-chapter-and-verse-divisions-international/11972#11972) Jews and Gentiles versify the Tanakh (i.e., assign its chapters and verses) quite a bit different. I have been trying to find an exhaustive list of the verses that differ between the Jewish translations and the KJV.

Could somebody give the list or at least a link where the differing verses/chapters are exhaustively enumerated?
Thanks, I have been looking for it for a while.

**Note:** To avoid confusion. I am not asking for the [difference in the books' order](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/does-the-christian-old-testament-have-the-exact-same-list-of-books-as-the-jewish), but the differences in verse/chapter in the same books.

Answer (score 6):

I have been working on [some software](https://github.com/curiousdannii/reversify) which converts between different versification systems. As part of that, I have a file listing the various differences: [transformations.data](https://github.com/curiousdannii/reversify/blob/master/src/transformations.data). There is no single "Jewish" translation, but I currently have included the NJPS. The JPS or Masoretic text probably have some differences elsewhere.

There is also [a long JSON file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curiousdannii/cac5d7d91b8a305b9dd63bab3aef65f6/raw/1345346540a265f2dc059194379eab3c3668e56a/book-chapter-lengths.json) detailing all the versification differences I'm aware of. I believe that "he_wlc" is the Leningrad codex, the source text of the standard BHS edition.

See also my page on [Versification systems resources](https://github.com/curiousdannii/reversify/wiki/Versification-systems-resources).

Comment: +1 Hey Danni, thanks a lot, this is already something to begin with. Although I have hardly worked with Java. I still hope for somebody to post a nice list of the verses that differ as intervals. :)
PS: Yes, you are right there is no "single" Jewish version.

Comment: It's Javascript not Java, and actually the transformations.data file is a nice human readable list of verses.